# How to remove xml or html command lines and retrieve actual text data using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

How to remove html or xml command lines from a downloaded webpage to obtain only text data during text preprocessing using python-3.x

I have tried by first removing special characters and numbers using str.translate and then crosschecking the tokens from english dictionary but some html commands still get included.

```
def rmpunctuation(text):

    chars_to_remove = "!\"·—#$%&'–()*+,-.•−⟨⟩/:;<=>? 
    @[\]^_`{|}~0123456789"

    tr = str.maketrans("", "", chars_to_remove)

    return text.translate(tr)


def dictcheck(text):

    a = []

    for i in range(0,len(text)):

        if(d.check(text[i]) == True):

            a.append(text[i])

    return a
```

i expect the output to be a list of all words which are actual text from the webpage and not some xml or html code.

Comment: post raw data example

Comment: What do you mean "html or xml command lines" ? Tags ? If yes, you want to use a proper XML or HTML parser instead (I suggest BeautifulSoup as it's the most likely to correctly handle invalid HTML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried regex?

If you include the following in your code it will remove URLs and your special characters from a string

```py
import re

clean_string= re.sub(r'http\S+', ' ', orginal_string)

#To remove the other characters that you have mentioned you could do the following:

clean_string= re.sub("!\"·—#$%&'–()*+,-.•−⟨⟩/:;<=>? 
    @[\]^_`{|}~0123456789", ' ', orginal_string)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. first error was shown but after using str(original_string), it did the trick